# What is the name of the algorithm that "inverts" the knapsack problem?

Tags: optimization, algorithms, convex-optimization

I know of the [knapsack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem. I want to find an algorithm that "inverts" the knapsack problem. My problem is as follows:

> Given a set of items, each with a weight and a value, determine the number of each item to include in a collection so that the total weight is **greater** than or equal to a given limit and the total value is as **small** as possible.

$$\min \sum _{i=1}^{n}v_{i}x_{i}$$
subject to

$$\sum _{i=1}^{n}w_{i}x_{i}\geq W $$

Is it still NP-hard problem?

Comment: Note that this is simply the dual version of the knapsack problem. It is weakly NP-hard and can be solved with dynamic programming.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the answer is yes, if the # of each item is bounded. Suppose you have two bags, namely, $B_1$ and $B_2$ and you want to distribute the items into these two bags. You want to determine the # of each item to include in $B_1$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i
$$
is **minimized** and at the same time,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i \geq W
$$
This is equivalent to determining the # of each item to include in $B_2$ such that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n v_ix_i
$$
is **maximized** and at the same time,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n w_ix_i \leq W'
$$
where $W' = \text{total weights of the items } - W$.

Comment: I tested it but it looks wrong. First, I download a MATLAB code which in https://kr.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22783-0-1-knapsack/content/knapsack.m?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com. then I apply the code with `weights = [1,  2,  3,  1,  5];
values =  [1,  1,  1,  1,  1];
total_weight=sum(weights);
W=8;
W_prime=total_weight-W
[best amount] = knapsack(weights, values, W_prime)` . It does not show what I expected. For example, amounts return the options w={1 2 1} does not true

Comment: @user3051460 If I understand correctly, what you have computed are items that should be put in $B_2$. If you remove these items, the remaining items are what you want.

Comment: Thanks. It means `weights=[3,5]`. Is it right?

Comment: @user3051460 Looks good to me.

Comment: Yes. But when I test with W=3. It returned weight=[5] in your suggest

Comment: @user3051460 Yes. $5 \geq 3$ and the value is minimum, i.e., $1$.

Comment: You are right. I was wrong. If I want to $\sum_i^n w_i x_i > W$ and the equal does not happen. What do I need change. For example, W=7, the above algorithm return [3,5] (correct) but I want [2,5]. Thank you again

Comment: @user3051460 $>W$ is equivalent to $\geq W + 1$ if weights are integers.

Comment: Thanks. I got it. I was wrong when ask about $> W$. Thank you. I accepted your answer

Comment: The above discussion must be as follows: "when $W=7$, we have two solutions $weight=[3,5]$ and $weight=[2,5]$. Is it possible to choose weights=[2,5]"?Sorry about my missing

Comment: @user3051460 I think it is possible to choose $[2, 5]$ instead, but this is not about the problem itself but about how you implement the algorithm, e.g., how you implement the dynamic programming.